# Save a CSV file that's too big to fit into memory into a parquet file

Tags: python, parquet

My development environment is a single-user workstation with 4 cores but not running Spark or HDFS. I have a CSV file that's too big to fit in memory. I want to save it as a parquet file and analyze it locally using existing tools, but have the ability to move it to the Spark cluster in the future and analyze it with Spark.

Is there any way to do this row-by-row without moving the file over to the Spark cluster?

I'm looking for a pure-python solution that does not involve the use of Spark.

Comment: Have a look into this thread, it may answer your question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900757/sequentially-read-huge-csv-file-in-python

Comment: Can you please mention why are you concerned about moving the file to the Spark Cluster?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save a huge pandas dataframe to hdfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393001/how-to-save-a-huge-pandas-dataframe-to-hdfs)

Comment: Not a duplicate, as I want to do this without spark and without HDFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the response of the [ostrokach answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45618618/) in question "How to convert a csv file to parquet" ,
and also based on the approach of [Zelazny7](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556579)  in question "Get inferred dataframe types iteratively using chunksize".

The approach to converting a CSV bigger than RAM to a parquet file, is in summary:

- Read the csv in chunks with a certain limit of RAM consumption in megabytes
- Create a parquet file from the schema optimally inferred from the entire CSV file
- Increment the parquet file by chunks of CSV data

This approach reads the entire CSV file to detect the most optimized data type for each column.

Then identifies the impact on RAM reduction and adjusts the chunksize that will be preserved in the parquet file as row_groups.

This approach, despite reading and writing the parquet file in chunks, is secure in terms of writing schema consistency and optimized in choosing the data type for each column.

**Mitigated schema risk**

Since the first chunk of data can have a column showing only integer data, the column will be identified as int64. If the schema of the parquet file is created by this first chunk, the assumed premise is that all other data in the csv file has an identical schema to the first chunk. But if in the last chunk, this same column has some missing data, the increment of the parquet file will result in a schema error because the int64 format does not support empty data.

To avoid the risk of a schema error, it is necessary to analyze the entire dataframe and identify each column by the broadest data type among all the data read.

### Convert csv bigger than RAM to parquet

```py
import numbers
import warnings
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Optional

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from pandas.errors import DtypeWarning

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DtypeWarning)


def get_chunksize_by_max_ram_mb(
    file_path: Path, max_ram_mb_per_chunk: int
) -> int:
    """Returns the amount of rows (chunksize) of a CSV that is approximately
    equivalent to the maximum RAM consumption defined.

    Args:
        file_path (Path): csv file path
        max_ram_mb_per_chunk (int): maximum consumption of RAM in mb

    Returns:
        int: chunksize
    """
    mb_size = file_path.stat().st_size / (1024**2)
    num_lines = sum(1 for _ in open(file_path))
    rows_per_chunk = (
        int(max_ram_mb_per_chunk / mb_size * num_lines / 3.5 / 10000) * 10000
    )
    return rows_per_chunk


def auto_opt_pd_dtypes(
    df_: pd.DataFrame, inplace=False
) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
    """Automatically downcast Number dtypes for minimal possible,
    will not touch other (datetime, str, object, etc)
    Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67403354
    :param df_: dataframe
    :param inplace: if False, will return a copy of input dataset
    :return: `None` if `inplace=True` or dataframe if `inplace=False`

    Opportunities for Improvement
    Optimize Object column for categorical
    Ref.: https://github.com/safurrier/data_science_toolbox/blob/master/data_science_toolbox/pandas/optimization/dtypes.py#L56
    """

    df = df_ if inplace else df_.copy()

    for col in df.columns:
        # integers
        if issubclass(df[col].dtypes.type, numbers.Integral):
            # unsigned integers
            if df[col].min() >= 0:
                df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], downcast="unsigned")
            # signed integers
            else:
                df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], downcast="integer")
        # other real numbers
        elif issubclass(df[col].dtypes.type, numbers.Real):
            df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], downcast="float")

    if not inplace:
        return df


def get_dtype_opt(csv_file_path, sep, chunksize, encoding):
    """
    Identifies the optimized data type of each column by analyzing
    the entire dataframe by chunks.
    Ref.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15556579

    return: dtype dict to pass as dtype argument of pd.read_csv
    """

    list_chunk = pd.read_csv(
        csv_file_path,
        sep=sep,
        chunksize=chunksize,
        header=0,
        low_memory=True,
        encoding=encoding,
    )

    list_chunk_opt = []
    for chunk in list_chunk:
        chunk_opt = auto_opt_pd_dtypes(chunk, inplace=False)
        list_chunk_opt.append(chunk_opt.dtypes)

    df_dtypes = pd.DataFrame(list_chunk_opt)
    dict_dtypes = df_dtypes.apply(
        lambda x: np.result_type(*x), axis=0
    ).to_dict()
    return dict_dtypes


def get_chunksize_opt(
    csv_file_path, sep, dtype, max_ram_mb_per_chunk, chunksize, encoding
):
    """After dtype optimization, analyzing only one data chunk,
    returns the amount of rows (chunksize) of a CSV that is
    approximately equivalent to the maximum RAM consumption.
    """

    for chunk in pd.read_csv(
        csv_file_path,
        sep=sep,
        dtype=dtype,
        chunksize=chunksize,
        low_memory=True,
        encoding=encoding,
    ):
        chunksize_opt = chunksize * (
            max_ram_mb_per_chunk
            / (chunk.memory_usage(deep=True).sum() / (1024**2))
        )
        break
    return int(chunksize_opt / 10_000) * 10_000


def write_parquet(
    csv_file_path, parquet_file_path, sep, dtype, chunksize, encoding
):
    """Write Parquet file from a CSV with defined dtypes and
    by chunks for RAM optimization.
    """

    for i, chunk in enumerate(
        pd.read_csv(
            csv_file_path,
            sep=sep,
            dtype=dtype,
            chunksize=chunksize,
            low_memory=True,
            encoding=encoding,
        )
    ):
        if i == 0:
            # Guess the schema of the CSV file from the first chunk
            parquet_schema = pa.Table.from_pandas(df=chunk).schema
            # Open a Parquet file for writing
            parquet_writer = pq.ParquetWriter(
                parquet_file_path, parquet_schema, compression="gzip"
            )
        # Write CSV chunk to the parquet file
        table = pa.Table.from_pandas(chunk, schema=parquet_schema)
        parquet_writer.write_table(table)

    parquet_writer.close()


def convert_csv_to_parquet(
    csv_file_path,
    parquet_file_path,
    max_ram_mb_per_chunk,
    sep=",",
    encoding="utf8",
):
    """Converts a CSV file to Parquet file, with maximum RAM consumption
    limit allowed and automatically optimizing the data types of each column.
    """

    chunksize = get_chunksize_by_max_ram_mb(
        csv_file_path, max_ram_mb_per_chunk
    )
    dict_dtypes_opt = get_dtype_opt(csv_file_path, sep, chunksize, encoding)
    chunksize_opt = get_chunksize_opt(
        csv_file_path,
        sep,
        dict_dtypes_opt,
        max_ram_mb_per_chunk,
        chunksize,
        encoding,
    )
    write_parquet(
        csv_file_path,
        parquet_file_path,
        sep,
        dict_dtypes_opt,
        chunksize_opt,
        encoding,
    )
```

#### Usage

```py
convert_csv_to_parquet(
    csv_file_path='input_big_csvfile.csv',
    parquet_file_path='output_parquetfile.parquet',
    max_ram_mb_per_chunk=100, sep=",", encoding="utf8")
```

#### Explanation

As the CSV file does not fit in RAM memory, the approach will respect a maximum allowed RAM consumption.

The steps:

- Finding the optimal chunksize for the first CSV scan.
- Identify the most optimized dtype for each column, respecting the defined maximum RAM consumption.
- After optimization, identify the number of rows that correspond to the defined maximum RAM consumption to serve as a basis for creating "num_row_groups" in the parquet file.
- Write parquet file respecting the defined maximum RAM consumption.

So, even if you only have 500mb of RAM available, you can convert a 10_000mb CSV to parquet and on top of that optimize the columns data types, which improves the reading speed and reduces the final file size even more.

### Read parquet file in chunk equivalent

```py
def read_by_row_group(parquet_file_path):
    parquet_file = pq.ParquetFile(parquet_file_path)
    for row_group in range(parquet_file.num_row_groups):
        yield parquet_file.read_row_group(row_group).to_pandas()
        
for df in read_by_row_group(parquet_file_path):
    
    # parsing
    pass
```

### Futher improvements

Implement data optimization of "object" dtype column to "categorical" dtype column, similar to what was implemented in [data_science_toolbox](https://github.com/safurrier/data_science_toolbox/blob/master/data_science_toolbox/pandas/optimization/dtypes.py#L56) , but in a chunk approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue with reading files large than memory. Spark can handle cases like this, without any adjustments, and

```
spark.read.csv(in_path).write.parquet(out_path)
```

will work just fine, as long as you don't use unsplittable compression for the input (`gzip` for example).

Comment: Yes, but we're trying to do this locally, without spark.

Comment: So why is it tagged [apache-spark]? :)

Comment: @alperttucker - I removed the Spark tag

Answer (score 0):

The pyarrow.parquet function write_to_dataset() looks like it may do this.
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#writing-to-partitioned-datasets

However I can't find detailed documentation for this function at the moment - you may need to look at the source code to see what it does.
https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/master/python/pyarrow/parquet.py, line 1154 at time of writing.

The pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter object might also do it..