# How would I go about converting a .csv to an .arrow file without loading it all into memory?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I found a similar question here: [Read CSV with PyArrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52413318/read-csv-with-pyarrow)

In this answer it references sys.stdin.buffer and sys.stdout.buffer, but I am not exactly sure how that would be used to write the .arrow file, or name it.
I can't seem to find the exact information I am looking for in the docs for pyarrow. My file will not have any nans, but it will have a timestamped index. The file is ~100 gb, so loading it into memory simply isn't an option. I tried changing the code, but as I assumed, the code ended up overwriting the previous file every loop.

***This is my first post. I would like to thank all the contributors who answered 99.9% of my other questions before I had even the asked them.

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

SPLIT_ROWS = 1     ### used one line chunks for a small test

def main():
    writer = None
    for split in pd.read_csv(sys.stdin.buffer, chunksize=SPLIT_ROWS):

        table = pa.Table.from_pandas(split)
        # Write out to file
        with pa.OSFile('test.arrow', 'wb') as sink:     ### no append mode yet
            with pa.RecordBatchFileWriter(sink, table.schema) as writer:
                writer.write_table(table)
    writer.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Below is the code I used in the command line

```
>cat data.csv | python test.py
```

Comment: Can you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555085/how-can-i-chunk-through-a-csv-using-arrow/68563617#68563617  and see if that helps?  It shows how to do this with a parquet file.  Doing this with a .arrow file should be pretty much the same process.  Open your writer once and then you can call write_table to it many times (once per chunk) and then you can close it at the end.

Comment: Your example is quite close too.  I think the thing you would want to change is to create the `RecordBatchFileWriter` outside the for loop.  You can then call `write_table` many times on the same instance.  Then you can close it after the for loop just like you are already doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @Pace, you should consider moving the output file creation outside of the reading loop. Something like this:

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

SPLIT_ROWS = 1     ### used one line chunks for a small test

def main():
    # Write out to file
    with pa.OSFile('test.arrow', 'wb') as sink:     ### no append mode yet
        with pa.RecordBatchFileWriter(sink, table.schema) as writer:
            for split in pd.read_csv('data.csv', chunksize=SPLIT_ROWS):
                table = pa.Table.from_pandas(split)
                writer.write_table(table)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You also don't have to use `sys.stdin.buffer` if you would prefer to specify specific input and output files. You could then just run the script as:

```
python test.py
```

By using `with` statements, both `writer` and `sink` will be automatically closed afterwards (in this case when `main()` returns). This means it should not be necessary to include an explicit `close()` call.

Comment: I went with this solution shown here. The schema needed to be defined before writer could write the file so I read the first two lines and defined it before looping through. It does assume consistent datatypes, but for my purposes, that will do just fine.

Answer (score 1):

in 2023 you don't need pandas for this. You can [chunk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68555085/how-can-i-chunk-through-a-csv-using-arrow) through csv using arrow:

```py
import pyarrow as pa
from pyarrow import csv

schema =  pa.schema([
        ('time', pa.timestamp('ms', None)),
        ('deviceid', pa.utf8())
])
convert_dict = {
  'time': pa.timestamp('ms', None),
  'deviceid': pa.utf8()
}
convert_options = pa.csv.ConvertOptions(
    column_types=convert_dict
    , strings_can_be_null=True
    , quoted_strings_can_be_null=True
    ,timestamp_parsers=["%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"],
)

arrowfile = "data_dst.arrow"
csvfile = "data_src.csv"

with pa.OSFile(arrowfile, 'wb') as sink:     ### no append mode yet
   with pa.csv.open_csv(csvfile, convert_options=convert_options) as reader:
       with pa.RecordBatchFileWriter(sink, schema) as writer:
           for next_chunk in reader:
               if next_chunk is None:
                    break
               if writer is None:
                    break
               next_table = pa.Table.from_batches([next_chunk])
               writer.write_table(next_table)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution adapted from @Martin-Evans code:

Closed file after the for loop as suggested by @Pace

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

SPLIT_ROWS = 1000000

def main():
    schema = pa.Table.from_pandas(pd.read_csv('Data.csv',nrows=2)).schema 
    ### reads first two lines to define schema 

    with pa.OSFile('test.arrow', 'wb') as sink:
        with pa.RecordBatchFileWriter(sink, schema) as writer:            
            for split in pd.read_csv('Data.csv',chunksize=SPLIT_ROWS):
                table = pa.Table.from_pandas(split)
                writer.write_table(table)

            writer.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Note: The use of `with` statements here is to ensure `sink` and `writer` are automatically closed afterwards, an explicit `close()` should not be needed.