# Automatically Optimizing Pandas Dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on an algorithm using the pandas library. I encountered an interesting problem while working.

when I write the dataframe object to the file and read it again, the dataframe changes. When I investigated the cause, I found that it was caused by types. For example I am creating a dataframe like the following;

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.col1 = df.col1.astype('int8')

df.info()
```

Output looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
col1    2 non-null int8
col2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), int8(1)
memory usage: 98.0 bytes
```

It is just 98 bytes.

I wrote it to the file and read it again.

```py
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
pd.read_csv('test.csv').info()
```

Output looks like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 2 columns):
col1    2 non-null int64
col2    2 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(2)
memory usage: 112.0 bytes
```

Now memory usage 112 bytes. The problem here is that when reading the csv file it reads as int64. I'm doing this on a large dataframe, and my file size of **250 mb** reaches **1.14 gb**

My question will be; Is there a way to automatically convert column types on the dataframe to the smallest possible size? I tried the function **infer_dtypes** but did not get the result I wanted. It says it should be integer as the type it should be.

Comment: Hi EmreAydin, if the problem is datatypes and memory usage you should consider save your data  to `.parquet`.

Answer (score 6):

Works for all Number types, helps to get rid of `np.int64` and `np.float64`:

```py
import numbers
import pandas as pd
from typing import Optional

def auto_opt_pd_dtypes(df_: pd.DataFrame, inplace=False) -> Optional[pd.DataFrame]:
    """ Automatically downcast Number dtypes for minimal possible,
        will not touch other (datetime, str, object, etc)
        
        :param df_: dataframe
        :param inplace: if False, will return a copy of input dataset
        
        :return: `None` if `inplace=True` or dataframe if `inplace=False`
    """
    df = df_ if inplace else df_.copy()
        
    for col in df.columns:
        # integers
        if issubclass(df[col].dtypes.type, numbers.Integral):
            # unsigned integers
            if df[col].min() >= 0:
                df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], downcast='unsigned')
            # signed integers
            else:
                df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], downcast='integer')
        # other real numbers
        elif issubclass(df[col].dtypes.type, numbers.Real):
            df[col] = pd.to_numeric(df[col], downcast='float')
    
    if not inplace:
        return df
```

Usage:

```
# return optimized copy
df_opt = auto_opt_pd_dtypes(df)
# or optimize in place
auto_opt_pd_dtypes(df, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Great solution, but pd.to_numeric(np.array([2.205001270000e09]).astype(np.float64), downcast="float") gives array([2.2050012e+09], dtype=float32), which is a loss of the last meaningful "7" (pd=1.4.4, np=1.21.5).

Comment: @AnatolyAlekseev Not with pd=2.1.1/np=1.26.0: stays float64.

Answer (score 5):

After some research, the to_numeric function works fine. I have implemented my own implementation as follows.

I created a dataframe object from numpy data types.

```
np_types = [np.int8 ,np.int16 ,np.int32, np.int64,
           np.uint8 ,np.uint16, np.uint32, np.uint64]
np_types = [np_type.__name__ for np_type in np_types]
type_df = pd.DataFrame(data=np_types, columns=['class_type'])
type_df
```

Result looks like this:

[image]

Then I added information about the types to the dataframe

```py
type_df['min_value'] = type_df['class_type'].apply(lambda row: np.iinfo(row).min)
type_df['max_value'] = type_df['class_type'].apply(lambda row: np.iinfo(row).max)
type_df['range'] = type_df['max_value'] - type_df['min_value']
type_df.sort_values(by='range', inplace=True)
type_df
```

[image]

then I wrote a function on integer columns to find out which type would be more appropriate over min and max values.

```
def optimize_types(dataframe):
for col in dataframe.loc[:, dataframe.dtypes <= np.integer]:
    col_min = dataframe[col].min()
    col_max = dataframe[col].max()
    temp = type_df[(type_df['min_value'] <= col_min) & (type_df['max_value'] >= col_max)]
    optimized_class = temp.loc[temp['range'].idxmin(), 'class_type']
    print("Col name : {} Col min_value : {} Col max_value : {} Optimized Class : {}".format(col, col_min, col_max, optimized_class))
    dataframe[col] = dataframe[col].astype(optimized_class)
return dataframe
```

I had a dataframe of 2.6 gb. With the above function, it went down to 600 mb.

[image]

[image]

When i use to_numeric function i got this results:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[`to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) has a downcast parameter. So you could downcast all numerical columns like this:

```
df.col1 = pd.to_numeric(df.col1, downcast='integer')
```

Example:

```
import io
s = """col1,col2,col3
1,1000000,'a'
"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))

df.info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
#Data columns (total 3 columns):
#col1    1 non-null int64
#col2    1 non-null int64
#col3    1 non-null object
#dtypes: int64(2), object(1)
#memory usage: 84.0+ bytes

num_cols = df.select_dtypes('number').columns
df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='integer'))

df.info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
#Data columns (total 3 columns):
#col1    1 non-null int8
#col2    1 non-null int32
#col3    1 non-null object
#dtypes: int32(1), int8(1), object(1)
#memory usage: 73.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Or just `df[num_cols] = df[num_cols].apply(pd.to_numeric, downcast='integer')`

Answer (score 0):

if the columns are all numeric you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
df = df.astype(np.int8)
```

if the columns are not all numeric you can first slice them, selecting the numeric ones, and then call `astype`.

Comment: The question was how to **automatically** optimize pandas dtypes. If your df contains e.g. `1000000` then your method will convert it to `64` **without any warning**!!!

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a file type that can serialize `python` objects. The `dtypes` will now persist. Here I use `pickle`. For large DataFrames, this can also lead to a big [performance improvement](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#performance-considerations) for IO operations.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['col1'] = df.col1.astype('int8')
```

---

```
df.info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
#Data columns (total 2 columns):
#col1    2 non-null int8
#col2    2 non-null int64
#dtypes: int64(1), int8(1)
#memory usage: 146.0 bytes

df.to_pickle('test.pkl')
pd.read_pickle('test.pkl').info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
#Data columns (total 2 columns):
#col1    2 non-null int8
#col2    2 non-null int64
#dtypes: int64(1), int8(1)
#memory usage: 146.0 bytes
```

---

The other option is to stick with `csv`, but maintain a schema of `{'col_name: 'dtype'}`. This can then be used whenever you read the file.

```
schema = {'col1': 'int8'}
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype=schema).info()
#<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
#RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
#Data columns (total 2 columns):
#col1    2 non-null int8
#col2    2 non-null int64
#dtypes: int64(1), int8(1)
#memory usage: 146.0 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

Further elaborating on @EmreAydin's answer, I wrote a function that obtains the smallest possible integer dtype of a given column, **wihtout the need to load the whole dataset in memory** (for very large datasets):

```py
def get_types(signed=True, unsigned=True, custom=[]):
    '''Returns a pandas dataframe containing the boundaries of each integer dtype'''
    # based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57894540/9419492
    pd_types = custom
    if signed:
        pd_types += [pd.Int8Dtype() ,pd.Int16Dtype() ,pd.Int32Dtype(), pd.Int64Dtype()]
    if unsigned:
        pd_types += [pd.UInt8Dtype() ,pd.UInt16Dtype(), pd.UInt32Dtype(), pd.UInt64Dtype()]
    type_df = pd.DataFrame(data=pd_types, columns=['pd_type'])
    type_df['np_type'] = type_df['pd_type'].apply(lambda t: t.numpy_dtype)
    type_df['min_value'] = type_df['np_type'].apply(lambda row: np.iinfo(row).min)
    type_df['max_value'] = type_df['np_type'].apply(lambda row: np.iinfo(row).max)
    type_df['allow_negatives'] = type_df['min_value'] < 0
    type_df['size'] = type_df['np_type'].apply(lambda row: row.itemsize)
    type_df.sort_values(by=['size', 'allow_negatives'], inplace=True)
    return type_df.reset_index(drop=True)

def downcast_int(file_path, column:str, chunksize=100000, delimiter=',', signed=True, unsigned=True):
    '''Automatically downcast Number dtype for minimal possible'''
    types = get_types(signed, unsigned)
    negatives = False
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=[column],delimiter=delimiter,chunksize=chunksize):
        M = chunk[column].max()
        m = chunk[column].min()
        if not signed and not negatives and m < 0 :
            types = types[types['allow_negatives']] # removes unsigned rows
            negatives = True
        if m < types['min_value'].iloc[0]:
            types = types[types['min_value'] < m]
        if M > types['max_value'].iloc[0]:
            types = types[types['max_value'] > M]
        if len(types) == 1:
            print('early stop')
            break
    return types['pd_type'].iloc[0]
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that widely recommended pd.to_numeric(x, downcast='float') does not mind losing precision. It hit me in the face when I blindly used it on a column containing occasional transaction IDs (there were nulls, so it was detected by pandas as float64).
But *pd.to_numeric(np.array([2.205001270000e09]).astype(np.float64), downcast="float")* gives *array([2.2050012e+09], dtype=float32)*, which is a loss of the last meaningful "7" (pd=1.4.4, np=1.21.5). Ended up using (slightly rusty) custom solution:

```
def optimize_dtypes(
    df: pd.DataFrame,
    max_categories: Optional[int] = 100,
    reduce_size: bool = True,
    float_to_int: bool = True,
    skip_columns: Sequence = (),
    verbose: bool = False,
    inplace: bool = True,
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    """Compress datatypes in a pandas dataframe to save space while keeping precision.
    Optionally attempts converting floats to ints where feasible.
    Optionally converts object fields with nuniques less than max_categories to categorical.
    """

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Inits
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    old_dtypes = {}
    new_dtypes = {}
    int_fields = []
    float_fields = []
    for field, the_type in df.dtypes.to_dict().items():
        if field not in skip_columns:
            old_dtypes[field] = the_type.name
            if "int" in the_type.name:
                int_fields.append(field)
            elif "float" in the_type.name:
                float_fields.append(field)

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Every object var with too few categories must become a Category
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if max_categories is not None:
        for col, the_type in old_dtypes.items():
            if "object" in the_type:
                if field in skip_columns:
                    continue
                try:
                    n = df[col].nunique()
                    if n <= max_categories:
                        new_dtypes[col] = "category"
                        if verbose:
                            logger.info("%s %s->category", col, the_type)
                        if inplace:
                            df[col] = df[col].astype(new_dtypes[col])
                except:
                    pass  # to avoid stumbling on lists like [1]

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Finds minimal size suitable to hold each variable of interest without loss of coverage
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if reduce_size:
        mantissas = {}
        uint_fields = []
        conversions = [
            (int_fields, "uint"),
            (int_fields, "int"),
        ]
        if float_to_int:

            # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            # Checks for each float if it has no fractional digits and NaNs, and, therefore, can be made an int
            # ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            possibly_integer = []
            for col in tqdmu(float_fields, desc="checking float2int"):
                if not (df[col].isna().any()):  # NAs can't be converted to int
                    fract_part, _ = np.modf(df[col])
                    if (fract_part == 0.0).all():
                        possibly_integer.append(col)
            if possibly_integer:
                conversions.append((possibly_integer, "uint"))
                conversions.append((possibly_integer, "int"))
        conversions.append((float_fields, "float"))
        for fields, type_name in tqdmu(conversions, desc="size reduction"):
            fields = [el for el in fields if el not in uint_fields]
            if len(fields) > 0:
                max_vals = df[fields].max()
                min_vals = df[fields].min()

                if type_name in ("int", "uint"):
                    powers = [8, 16, 32, 64]
                    topvals = [np.iinfo(type_name + str(p)) for p in powers]
                elif type_name == "float":
                    powers = [16, 32, 64]  # no float8
                    topvals = [np.finfo(type_name + str(p)) for p in powers]

                min_max = pd.concat([min_vals, max_vals], axis=1)
                min_max.columns = ["min", "max"]

                for r in min_max.itertuples():
                    col = r.Index
                    cur_power = int(old_dtypes[col].replace("uint", "").replace("int", "").replace("float", ""))
                    for j, p in enumerate(powers):
                        if p >= cur_power:
                            if not (col in float_fields and type_name != "float"):
                                break
                        if r.max <= topvals[j].max and r.min >= topvals[j].min:
                            if type_name == "float":
                                # need to ensure we are not losing precision! np.array([2.205001270000e09]).astype(np.float64) must not pass here, for example.
                                if col not in mantissas:
                                    values = df[col].values
                                    _, int_part = np.modf(np.log10(np.abs(values)))
                                    mantissa = np.round(values / 10**int_part, np.finfo(old_dtypes[col]).precision - 1)
                                    mantissas[col] = mantissa
                                else:
                                    mantissa = mantissas[col]

                                fract_part, _ = np.modf(mantissa * 10 ** (np.finfo("float" + str(p)).precision + 1))
                                fract_part, _ = np.modf(np.round(fract_part, np.finfo("float" + str(p)).precision - 1))
                                if (np.ma.array(fract_part, mask=np.isnan(fract_part)) != 0).any():  # masking so that NaNs do not count
                                    if verbose:
                                        logger.info("Column %s can't be converted to float%s due to precision loss.", col, p)
                                    break
                            if type_name in ("uint", "int"):
                                uint_fields.append(col)  # successfully converted, so won't need to consider anymore
                            if verbose:
                                logger.info("%s [%s]->[%s%s]", col, old_dtypes[col], type_name, p)
                            new_dtypes[col] = type_name + str(p)
                            if inplace:
                                df[col] = df[col].astype(new_dtypes[col])
                            break

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Actual converting & reporting.
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if len(new_dtypes) > 0 and not inplace:
        if verbose:
            logger.info(f"Going to use the following new dtypes: {new_dtypes}")
        return df.astype(new_dtypes)
    else:
        return df
```

Comment: Not with pd=2.1.1/np=1.26.0: anything above 2.204e9 stays float64.

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest write the dataframe into pkl as below: df.to_pickle("filename.pkl")